# Do `chrome.webNavigation.on*` methods work on `chrome-extension://` URLs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**CONTEXT**
My company has an extension that dynamically creates iframes that point to a static web_accessible_resources `index.html` file. I'm trying to run a content script in each of those iframes (to set up a `chrome.runtime.Port` between each iframe and the extension service worker).

**PROBLEM**
It seems `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted` is not running on `chrome-extension://` URLs. I've also tried <s>`onCommitted`</s> and `onDOMContentLoaded`. *Correction: onCommitted works.*

My plan was to use `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted` to detect new `chrome-extension://` frames. I've tried with and without a URL filter `{ url: [{ urlPrefix: chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html')}] }`. When I remove the URL filter, I see all kinds of navigations EXCEPT `chrome-extension://...` URLs. Kinda frustrating to see everything including `about:blank` and `chrome://...` frames, but not my index.html haha.

I'm going to try `webRequest` next, but I wanted to ask here first.

**EXAMPLE**

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
  console.log('index.html visited!')
  // chrome.scripting.executeScript(...) or whatever else.
}, { url: [{ urlPrefix: chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html')}] } )
```

This does not run when you navigate to `chrome-extension://.../index.html`. Whether a top-level navigation or a subframe navigation, neither trigger the event.

**UPDATE** 
`webRequest` doesn't work either. Also, `window.frames` doesn't include subframes with `chrome-extension://` URLs either. My guess is it's a security strategy due to the following:

**An interesting finding** 
`chrome-extension://` frames have access to extension APIs, same as a service worker. *(This is actually solves what I was trying to do, but I think it's still worth talking about `webNavigation` and `webRequest` not triggering on `chrome-extension://` URLs.)*

Comment: Yes, some of them work like onCommitted and there's no need to specify `url` or do anything special. Show an [MCVE](/help/mcve) for how do you open/run index.html and your listeners.

Comment: @wOxxOm I added an example.

Comment: I've just verified, like I said, onCommitted works in this scenario. I guess you didn't reload the extension after changing the code to onCommitted or there was a bug in Chrome and it retained the old code.

Comment: @wOxxOm oh interesting, yeah, I'm able to get onCommitted callbacks. I must've not reloaded my local build. No for onDOMContentLoaded.
Do you know of any documentation for these behaviors? Thank you for your help, btw. If you write up an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: It's not documented, so the difference may be due to a bug. I'm also not sure it works in Firefox.